# How do I create a dictionary in Python when a user inputs a list of words that are to be the keys and values?

Tags: python, dictionary

*6.19.1: LAB: Replacement words:*

Write a program that replaces words in a sentence. The input begins with word replacement pairs (original and replacement). The next line of input is the sentence where any word on the original list is replaced.

**Ex: If the input is:**

automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids

The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.

**the output is:**

The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.
You can assume the original words are unique.

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Now I can just add those to a dictionary, however, those words change. So how do I add a user's input to a dictionary and differentiate between the key and value for the dictionary?

The Code as it stands now after a lot of deleting and retrying:

```
my_dict = {}  #creates a dictionary
user_words = input().split() #seperates the users words

#fixme FIRST WORD THE KEY AND THE SECOND WORD THE VALUE for len(user_words)
#fixme REPLACE KEYS AND VALUES IF KEY IN SECOND USER INPUT

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: Loop through `user_words` in pairs, adding them as key and value to `my_dict`.

Comment: If you have a single key and value in a variable, can you write code that updates the dictionary to add that key-value pair? Given the `user_words`, can you figure out what the first key and value should be? Can you figure out what the second key and value should be? Can you think of a way to repeat the process with each pair of words? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions , and try to break the problem down into logical steps and figure out exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: E.g. `my_dict[user_words[i]] = user_words[i+1]`

Comment: "and differentiate between the key and value for the dictionary" I don't think I understand what you mean. The words in the input are in order. You know that `automobile` is a key and `car` is a value because `automobile` came first and `car` was after it, and then the next word has to be a key again. What's the difficulty here?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    replaces = input('replaces: ').split(' ')
    # automobile car manufacturer maker children kids
    replaces_dict = dict(zip(replaces[0::2], replaces[1::2]))
    text = input('text: ')
    # The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.

    new_text = []
    for word in text.split(' '):
        new_text.append(replaces_dict.get(word, word))
    print(' '.join(new_text))
    # output:
    # The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question, I think this might work for you:

```
for i in range(len(user_words)-1):
    my_dict[user_words[i]] = user_words[i+1]
```